# REST API patch allows me to write invalid picklist values to Opportunity.StageName

Tags: rest-api, picklist, opportunity, patch, stagename

After running this...

```bash
curl -X PATCH "https://custom.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0060900000OWbmEAAT" \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer INTENTIONALLY_REMOVED' \
  --header 'X-PrettyPrint:1' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"StageName":"INVALID"}'
```

It succeeds and sets the Opportunity.StageName to "INVALID" on the Opportunity Lightning Record Page...

[image]

...and adds INVALID to the list of Inactive picklist values:

[image]

Is there a way to get an error when I try to patch a picklist field with an invalid value?

While I can get the results of a query like `SELECT MasterLabel FROM OpportunityStage` first to validate the new StageName is there, this would be slower.

I guess this issue is about Opportunity.StageName being an unrestricted picklist when I want it to behave like a restricted one. Is there a way to change that without creating a custom picklist that stands in for Stage?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what actually happens - and cover what the picklist field definition looks like (you may have an unrestricted picklist, in which case new entries get added when you provide an unrecognised value).

Comment: Thanks - just updated the question to make it more explicit. Is there a way to make a built-in picklist like Stage restricted?

Comment: I think you need to put a validation rule rule in place to only allow specific values. You can also [upvote this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWyAUAV/restrict-pickllist-values-for-a-standard-field).